# Replace newline at the end of string in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file in my desktop containing the following line only

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test\not-84949685 .txt_Fetched.txt\n"
```

In that , I just want to remove only "\n" at the end of the line
For that, i have written code as

```
List = "C:\\Users\\Pavithran\\Desktop\\list.txt"
with open(List,'r') as readfile:
     content = readfile.readlines()
for i in content:
    i = i.replace ("\\n","")
    print i
```

Output of that code:

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Testot-84949685 .txt_Fetched.txt"
```

It also replace the \n after the test..

**Expected Output :**

```
"C:\Users\Adminstrator\Desktop\Test\not-84949685 .txt_Fetched.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with the pattern `\n(?="$)` to specifically target a newline occurring at the very end of the input.

```
input = "\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Test\\not-84949685 .txt_Fetched.txt\n\""
print(re.sub(r"\n(?=\"$)", "", input))
print("Hello World!")

"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test\not-84949685 .txt_Fetched.txt"
Hello World!       <-- I added this to show that the newline was removed
```

### Demo

Comment: It need double quotes in that line.Your output contain without quotes

Comment: So then the newline you want to replace is the one right before the final quote, is that correct?

Comment: ..Yes i just need to remove the newline at the end

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Tim is elegant and go to solution for such issues.

BTW if you just want to remove the last character (yes `'\n'` is just one character instead of two), you can use Python string slicing:

```
List = "C:\\Users\\Pavithran\\Desktop\\list.txt"

with open(List,'r') as readfile:
    for line in readfile:
        line = line[:-1]
```

The variable `line` now contains the expected output.